# Unity Desktop: Couldn't find a perfect decorator match

Tags: unity, 11.04

I am using Ubuntu 11.4 alpha3 just to test it. Unity desktop loads without top panel and left dock.

After some help I got this command and tried it.

```
unity --replace
```

Here is the output

```
unity-panel-service: no process found
libcompizconfig: dlopen: /usr/lib/compizconfig/backends/libgconf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**This file is locate at `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/libgconf.so`**

```
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : ini
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing session options...done
Couldn't find a perfect decorator match; trying all decorators
Found no decorator to start
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How to investigate the issue and fix it.

Comment: c'mon buddy, it's the alpha version, it **would be** unstable!

Comment: well, i still got this in released oneiric, for some reason.  **i wish** these were too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this command:

```
unity --reset
```

Also, make sure you have the `compiz-gnome` package installed. This package contains `unity-window-decorator`. Run this command to ensure that `compiz-gnome` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-gnome
```

Comment: Ya, it was compiz issue, it was there but with some conflict, reinstalled and fixed. :)

Comment: That fixed it for me.